# How to Alphabetize Store Location Listings

Tags: php

I have a "Locations" module in our Magento store, but it spits out all of our store locations in a random order. It does list them by "State", but if there's 5 New Jersey listings, it doesn't alphabetize based on the Store name. This is the code we have now. This is the live locations page

http://www.jennyyoo.com/index.php/locations/

```
<div class="std locations">
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>US LOCATIONS:</li>
            <?php for ($i = 65; $i <= 90; $i++): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('jennyyoo_locations') ?>#letter-<?php echo chr($i) ?>"><?php echo chr($i) ?></a></li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('jennyyoo_locations/international') ?>">INTERNATIONAL</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="legend">
            <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/bridal-gowns.gif'); ?>"/>Bridal gowns</li>
            <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/brides-maids.gif'); ?>"/>Bridesmaids</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <?php foreach ($states as $state): ?>
            <div class="state-wrapper">
                <h5 <?php if (!in_array(substr($state['region'], 0, 1), $used_letters)) {echo 'id="letter-' . substr($state['region'], 0, 1) . '"'; $used_letters[] = substr($state['region'], 0, 1); } ?>>
                    <span><?php echo $state['region']; ?></span>
                </h5>
                <?php $locations = $this->getStateLocations($state['region']); ?>
                <?php foreach ($locations as $location): ?>
                    <div class="location-wrapper">
                        <h6>
                            <?php echo $location['name']; ?>
                            <?php if ($location['bridal_gowns']){?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/bridal-gowns.gif'); ?>"/>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if ($location['bridesmaids']){?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/brides-maids.gif'); ?>"/>
                            <?php }?>
                        </h6>
                        <address>
                            <?php echo nl2br($location['address_display']); ?>
                        </address>
                        <span class="www-url"><a href="<?php echo $location['website_url']; ?>"><?php echo $location['website_url']; ?></a></a>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `php` question and should be asked in stackoverflow. This is Magento dedicated SE site.

However, I will still try to answer here.

You just need to use one of the `php` [sort function](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

In your case, I would use `asort($array)`, this uses `value` to sort.

So your code should be:

```
<div class="std locations">
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>US LOCATIONS:</li>
            <?php for ($i = 65; $i <= 90; $i++): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('jennyyoo_locations') ?>#letter-<?php echo chr($i) ?>"><?php echo chr($i) ?></a></li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('jennyyoo_locations/international') ?>">INTERNATIONAL</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="legend">
            <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/bridal-gowns.gif'); ?>"/>Bridal gowns</li>
            <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/brides-maids.gif'); ?>"/>Bridesmaids</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="listing">
        <?php foreach ($states as $state): ?>
            <div class="state-wrapper">
                <h5 <?php if (!in_array(substr($state['region'], 0, 1), $used_letters)) {echo 'id="letter-' . substr($state['region'], 0, 1) . '"'; $used_letters[] = substr($state['region'], 0, 1); } ?>>
                    <span><?php echo $state['region']; ?></span>
                </h5>
                <?php $locations = $this->getStateLocations($state['region']); ?>
                <?php foreach ($locations as $location): ?>
                    <div class="location-wrapper">
                        <h6>
                            <?php echo $location['name']; ?>
                            <?php if ($location['bridal_gowns']){?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/bridal-gowns.gif'); ?>"/>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php if ($location['bridesmaids']){?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/brides-maids.gif'); ?>"/>
                            <?php }?>
                        </h6>
                        <address>
                            <?php echo nl2br($location['address_display']); ?>
                        </address>
                        <span class="www-url"><a href="<?php echo $location['website_url']; ?>"><?php echo $location['website_url']; ?></a></a>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Since `asort()` doesn't work in multidimensional array, you should use `usort()` in this case.

I recommend using this in your `block` file rather than `phtml` file.

In your block file, sort your `$states` as follow:

```
$newStates = array();
foreach ($states as $key => $row) {
    // replace 0 with the field's index/key
    $newStates[$key]  = $row[0];
}

$finalStates = array_multisort($newStates, SORT_DESC, $states);
```

Then call your `$finalStates` in your `phtml` file.

**Assumption**

1. `$states` is an multidimensional array

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, but unfortunately this code didn't work, and broke the code. :(

Comment: Check my update.